# Entity Framework virtual property return null (interestingly it happens sometime)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my ASP.NET MVC project I'm using Entity Framework 6 to get data from database.

I have two tables `Project` with a relation to `ProjectPersonel`.

The following code are the entity classes:

```
public class Project
{
     [DataMember]
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name{ get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<ProjectPersonel> ProjectPersonels { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectPersonel 
{
     [DataMember]
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     public virtual int Id { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey("Project")]
     public int ProjectId { get; set; }

     public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code writes the certain project personel count.

```
Project project = SelectWithId(id);
WriteToScreen(project.ProjectPersonels.Count());
```

While debugging, everything is fine, but on the server, it writes different values to screen.

For example I saw 0,1,2,3,4 and 5 numbers for the project which has 5 personel.

I tried two different database but the result is same.

Can you think of what's wrong?

Comment: I cant see primary key in your project table. Can you add it and try again?

Comment: there is primary key i edited my question

Comment: Please show the query you are using to get the data. Share entire method starting from creation of Datacontext object to access of data for `SelectWithId`

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour will happen in cases where lazy loading has been turned off or otherwise disconnected from the DbContext and the query does not eager-load the related data and where DbContexts are relatively long-lived.

Say you have a Project that references 3 Personnel with Personnel IDs 1, 2, and 3. When you tell EF to fetch that project, it will see the FKs for Personnel 1, 2, & 3, and check it's cache to see if those entities are available and associate them.  So if the DbContext instance had earlier loaded Personnel ID 1 & 2, and you fetch that Project, the Personnel count would be 2 instead of 3.

To see the behaviour in practice given a 1 to many relationship between Project and ProjectPersonnel where Project ID 1 has 3 personnel (1,2,3)

With Eager Loading:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   var project = context.Projects.Include(x => x.Personnel).Single(x => x.Id == 1);
   Assert.AreEqual(3, project.Personnel.Count);
}
```

This will go and select all personnel for Project #1 along with that project, resulting in a count of 3.

With Lazy Loading:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   var project = context.Projects.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
   Assert.AreEqual(3, project.Personnel.Count);
}
```

Provided lazy loading is enabled then this too will return the 3 personnel. The difference is that your .Single() call will just load the Project without any personnel, however when the code attempts to access the Personnel property on the project, it will trigger another load against the DbContext to load the Personnel for that project.

However, if you turn off lazy loading:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   var project = context.Projects.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
   Assert.AreEqual(3, project.Personnel.Count);
}
```

In your case this will fail with your NullReferenceException due to the collection not being loaded and not lazy loading. If we change the property to:

```
public virtual ICollection<ProjectPersonel> ProjectPersonels { get; set; } = new List<ProjectPersonel>();
```

just to ensure the collection is always accessible, we will see that the Personnel collection is left empty where the context doesn't have anything to fill in. This is where it gets interesting. Lets simulate loading some of the related data:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   var somePersonnel = context.Personnel.Where(x => x.Id == 2 || x.Id == 3);
   var project = context.Projects.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
   Assert.AreEqual(3, project.Personnel.Count);
}
```

We leave lazy loading off, but we load Personnel IDs # 2 & 3 as part of an earlier operation. In this case when we go to load the project (with FKs pointing to personnel #1, 2, & 3) this test will still fail because it will report the Personnel count on the project as 2, not 3 because EF found the 2 previously loaded entities and attached them. Now this example seems silly, but in many cases if a DbContext is left alive for a long time or passed through multiple methods that may conditionally start loading various bits and pieces of data, later queries will pick out those previously loaded entities when they find them. Long lived DbContexts can start to "bog down" in performance as more and more entities are tracked and inspected with each query for associations to fill in.

This gets even more interesting when some operations might load Personnel ahead of time, but use `.AsNoTracking()` as entities loaded with this option are not tracked by the DbContext and aren't associated.

What to take away from this: Long-lived DbContexts lead to odd, inconsistent behviour like this. One of the problems with long-lived DbContexts is that you can't count on what is cached, and what isn't. Many times I've seen projects where a bug has cropped up where a performance problem was encountered and "solved" by someone changing a query or `Include` to `.AsNoTracking()` only to introduce a bug somewhere else because earlier the DbContext would have associated entities even though the query was not lazy loading, and now those would-be associated entities are no longer tracked. Then you get that "fixed" by re-enabling lazy-loading, and the vicious cycle of performance issues goes round and round.

Steps to avoid issues like this:
Keep the scope/lifespan of DbContexts short, and leverage EF's `IQueryable` interface and `Select()` to query the data you need rather than relying on Eager or Lazy loading and working with entire entities. The prime culprit for developers to consider turning off lazy loading or using `.AsNoTracking` is invariably for performance reasons. Instead, if you adopt leveraging `Select` to pull just the data you need from an entity hierarchy, and avoid pitfalls like using .ToList() to early in a EF Linq expression you can boost performance immensely and avoid surprises.

For example:

```
var project = context.Projects
   .Select(x => new ProjectViewModel
   {
      ProjectId = x.Id,
      Name = x.Name,
      Personnel = x.Personnel.Select(p => new PersonnelViewModel
      {
         PersonnelId = x.Id,
         Name = x.Name
      }).ToList()
    }.Single(x => x.Id == 1);
```

This does not require eager loading via `Include`, nor does it trip lazy load calls. It also gives you the benefit of filtering down just the fields you care about, and even just the associated records you care about. For example, several times on StackOverflow you will find questions like "How do I include just some associated entities?" (I.e. I want to include just active Personnel)  Dealing with EF entities, you can't; But leveraging `Select`? No problem:

```
  // ...
  Personnel = x.Personnel.Where(p => p.IsActive)
      .Select(p => new PersonnelViewModel
      {
         PersonnelId = x.Id,
         Name = x.Name
      }).ToList()
```

Hopefully that explains the behaviour your seeing and gives others that come across this question with odd behaviour of their own a bit of insight into EF's DbContext. :)